# Facebook LoginView Delegate Called Twice in different View Controllers

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the current navigation setup:

VC A: User can login via `FBLoginView`

VC B: User can create an account via `FBLoginView` (pushed onto VC stack from VC A)

Unfortunately, click the `FBLoginView` in VC B runs sucesfully, and then calls the delegate method `loginViewFetchedUserInfo` in VC A.

Even adding the following did not work in VC A:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];    
  self.loginView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  self.loginView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you set VC B's FBLoginView's delegate to VC A... How exactly did you set the delegate in VC B?

Comment: In code, and no its not. I checked storyboard as well and it is not. this is a known issue-I'm trying to find another SO thread that had a comment with this issue